# How can I get a specific page of results from WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress

Lets say my query look something like this:

```
WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'milkshakes',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
)
```

And lets say there are 20 milkshakes.
How can I return only the milkshake from page 5?

I'm asking because I'm creating a REST API endpoint and I'm looking to recreate ?page=5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress provides REST API you can use them, It come with a very good documentation. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

To return only the milkshake from page 5, pass paged parameter.

```
WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'milkshakes',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'paged' => 5
)
```